# Presentation of an Aggregate Member

Tags: oop, architecture, domain-driven-design

How do you expose an aggregate member for the purpose of presentation, while at the same time preventing that member from getting modified directly? So, I need something like read-only access to that member for the purpose of showing it on UI, For example:

```java
class A {

    B b;

    void doSomething() {
        b.update();
    }

}

class B {

    String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    void update() {
        ...
    }

}

interface SomeView {

    void show(Items items);

}
```

The quick-and-dirty solution would be to add a method `A::getB()` and call `someView.show(b.getItems())` but then the returned `B` instance could be modified outside of `A` (the `B::update()` could be called outside `A`).

I am thinking of several solutions but not quite sure which are best or if there is already a common practice to do so.

One of the solution that I have in mind is having a read-only version of `B` that is returned by `A`.

```java
class A {

    ReadOnlyB getReadOnlyB() {
        return new ReadOnlyB(b);
    }

}

class ReadOnlyB {

    B b;

    ReadOnlyB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    String getTitle() {
        return b.getTitle();
    }

    Items getItems() {
        return b.getItems();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have layers in your application? If so, what is their dependency schema? How do you isolate them from each other?

Comment: I have the domain layer, the API layer, and the presentation layer. Actually for the View, I would use `ItemPresentation` instead of just `Item` and have `ItemMapper` to map the `Item` to `ItemPresentation`.

Comment: Anyway, even for entity of the same layer, the `A::getB()` would still not be a good thing. Like if there is a separate class `C` that also belongs to the domain layer, it still wouldn't be good for `C` to be able to access `B` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use read-only interfaces for `B`. Internally, in `A` class, you use the class `B` but to the outside (to the clients) you give a read-only interface of `B`. Here is a sample:

```
class A 
{
    private B b;

    void doSomething() {
        //internally you use this.b
        b.update();
    }

    //please name this method according to its purpose
    ReadOnlyB getB()
    {
       return b;
    }
}

class B implements ReadOnlyB
{
    String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    void update() {
        ...
    }

}

//please name this interface according to its purpose!
interface ReadOnlyB
{
    Items getItems();
}

interface SomeView 
{
    void show(Items items);
}
```

However, this would break the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). It would be better to return the `Items` from `A`, like this:

```
class A 
{
    private B b;

    void doSomething() {
        b.update();
    }

    Items getItems()
    {
       return b.getItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is close to the solution that I chose in the end. Good point that you mentioned `A::getItems` too.

Comment: Btw, regarding the Law of Demeter, as the ReadOnlyB is essentially now just a value object / data structure, I don't think we break the law. It would be breaking the Law of Demeter if we're exposing an entity / object (with behaviour and stuffs).

Comment: @PabloEspantoso if you do this `a.getReadOnlyB().getItems()` you break the *law*

Comment: What about the following: `Triangle::getReadOnlyPoints().get(0).getX()`? Or should it be `Triangle::getFirstPointX()`?

Comment: Here's a quote from Clean Code: "Whether this is a violation of Demeter depends on whether or not ctxt, Options, and ScratchDir are objects or data structures. If they are objects, then their internal structure should be hidden rather than exposed, and so knowledge of their innards is a clear violation of the Law of Demeter. On the other hand, if ctxt, Options, and ScratchDir are just data structures with no behavior, then they naturally expose their internal structure, and so Demeter does not apply." In my case, the `getItems` also returns data structures (read-only, e.g: ReadOnlyItems).

Comment: @PabloEspantoso so it depends on the context and only you know if it's the case or not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expose domain objects to the presentation layer, map them to readonly presentation models (from your comment, that's already what you identified as the next thing to do).

You can have a look at CQRS for a stricter, more opinionated take on read models.

> Anyway, even for entity of the same layer, the `A::getB()` would still
>   not be a good thing.

If you stay inside the domain layer, it's actually legit. Entities can have references to other entities - including transient references to entities from other aggregates. However, if A and B belong to different aggregates, you must be aware that it violates the *Aggregate as consistency boundary* approach since you're now prone to modifying multiple aggregates in the same transaction. You're also making your life harder by increasing the chances of concurrent access to B.

Comment: `If you stay inside the domain layer, it's actually legit.` Hmmm, that's interesting. Anyway, I think this is a separate problem. Will take a look on how I could do it with CQRS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also let the objects *present themselves*, in which case there would be absolutely no need to expose hidden structures. This would be more in line with Object-Orientation, Law-of-Demeter, etc. Like this:

```java
public class A {
    private B b;
    ...
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        ...
        b.paint(g);
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, using a Wicket-type presentation to Web:

```java
public class A {
    private B b;
    ...
    public Component display() {
        return new APanel(..., b.display(), ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I probably won't do it that way because the domain itself is not about graphics.

Comment: I mean it would not make sense to have something like class Employee with a paint method.

Comment: @PabloEspantoso, you missed the point. This post is not about graphics, but more about OOP. Paint is just an example, in your case method could be called something like convert.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky I don't think having `convert` on the domain entity would make sense either, because that means that the domain entity needs to know about the type it should be converted to (in this case the data type of the layer above it, i.e: presentation layer).